# Transform dataframe based on multiple IDs and breaking two columns to a sequence of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the data below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'origin':  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'destination': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'set': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'pointA': [1, 11, 12, 1, 11, 13, 1, 16, 17, 18],
    'pointB': [11, 12, 2, 11, 13, 2, 16, 17, 18, 3],
    'time': [5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 7, 3, 4]}
datainput = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['origin','destination','set', 'pointA', 'pointB', 'time'])
```

which looks something like this:

```
origin  destination  set  pointA  pointB  time
  1         2         1      1      11     5
  1         2         1      11     12     6
  1         2         1      12     2      5
  1         2         2      1      11     5
  1         2         2      11     13     5
  1         2         2      13     2      7
  1         3         1      1      16     8
  1         3         1      16     17     7
  1         3         1      17     18     3
  1         3         1      18     3      4
```

I'd like to pivot the pointA and pointB columns into series of points while summing up the time, i.e. having one row for each unique [origin, destination, set], so desired output to look something like this:

```
origin  destination  set  point1  point2  point3  point4  point5 time
  1         2         1     1       11      12      2       0     16
  1         2         2     1       11      13      2       0     17
  1         3         1     1       16      17      18      3     22
```

To begin with, i've tried the pivot function as below:

`pivot = datainput.pivot_table(index=['origin', 'destination', 'set'], values=['time'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()`

This can get me the time sum for the unique [origin, destination, set]. However, i'm struggling to add the pointA and pointB to the picture being point1, point2, etc.

I've explored the potential of a transpose:

```
transposedData = datainput.T
```

But this just transposes the dataframe ending up with the many [origin, destination, set] being transorfed into columns. it's also hard to work with given the number of maximum points for the unique [origin, destination, set] is also unknow, in here i'm using 5 for the sample of data, however, my input file will be massive and i don't know what's the maximum number.

Any ideas of how to do this? links to readings about ways will also be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

datainput["pointC"]=list(zip(datainput["pointA"], datainput["pointB"]))

res=pd.pivot_table(datainput, index=["origin", "destination", "set"], aggfunc=lambda x: (np.unique(np.hstack(x.values.ravel()).astype(str))).tolist(), values=["pointC"]).pointC.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
origin  destination  set  0   1   2   3  4
0       1            2    1  1  11  12   2  0
1       1            2    2  1  11  13   2  0
2       1            3    1  1  16  17  18  3

[Program finished]
```